# python pop() for list with transfered value

Tags: python-3.x

I want to retain the original list while manipulating it i.e I'm using it in a loop and have to perform some operations each iteration so need to reset the value of a list. Initially, I thought it was a problem with my loops but I have narrowed it down to.

```
inlist=[1,2,3]

a=inlist
a.pop(0)
print(a)
print(inlist)
```

gives an output of

```
[2,3]
[2,3]
```

Why am I not getting

```
[2,3]
[1,2,3]
```

It is applying pop to both a and inlist.

Comment: You are just passing a reference. Trying copying the list to create a copy, i.e. `a = inlist.copy()`.

Comment: Because there is *only one list* which you've assigned to two different variables. Read the following: https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me explain with Interactive console:

```py
>>> original_list = [1, 2, 3, 4]  # source
>>> reference = original_list  # 'aliasing' to another name.

>>> reference is original_list  # check if two are referencing same object.
True

>>> id(reference)  # ID of referencing object
1520121182528
>>> id(original_list)  # Same ID
1520121182528
```

To create new list:

```py
>>> copied = list(original_list)
>>> copied is original_list  # now referencing different object.
False

>>> id(copied)  # now has different ID with original_list
1520121567616
```

There's multiple way of copying lists, for few examples:

```py
>>> copied_slicing = original_list[::]
>>> id(copied_slicing)
1520121558016

>>> import copy
>>> copied_copy = copy.copy(original_list)
>>> id(copied_copy)
1520121545664

>>> copied_unpacking = [*original_list]
>>> id(copied_unpacking)
1520123822336
```

.. and so on.

---

Image from book 'Fluent Python' by Luciano Ramalho might help you understand what's going on:

[image]

Rather than 'name' being a box that contains respective object, it's a **Post-it** stuck at object in-memory.

Answer (score 1):

Try doing it this way

```
a = [1,2,3]
b=[]
b.extend(a)
b.pop(0)
```

Although what you are doing makes sense but what is happening is that you are just assigning **another variable to the same list**, which is why both are getting affected. However if you define b(in my case) as an empty list and then assign it, you are then making a copy as compared to another variable pointing to the same list.